# Помогите найти метод для сортировки листа

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста как отсортировать лист.

Здесь у меня пример как у меня отсортирован лист по имени

```
list.Sort(new Comparison<Third>(MyDelegatName));
foreach (var v in list)
    Console.WriteLine(v.firstName);

static int MyDelegatName(Third st1, Third st2)
    return String.Compare(st1.firstName, st2.firstName);
```

А я вот хочу отсортировать по числам. Так не выходит, не ругается, просто выводит без сортировки

```
list.Sort(new Comparison<Third>(MyDelegatAge));
foreach (var v in list)
    Console.WriteLine(v.age);

static int MyDelegatAge(Third st1, Third st2)
    if (st1.age > st2.age)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
```

Comment: `st1.Age.CompareTo(st2.Age)`

Comment: Не редактируйте ответ, а оставляйте под ним комментарии вместо этого. Так же, если ответ вам помог, вы можете просто отметить его галочкой, которая расположена в левой части ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```cs
list.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    if (x.age < y.age)
        return 1;

    if (x.age > y.age)
        return -1;

    return 0;
});
```

@AlexanerPetrov предложил более лаконичный вариант на основе стандартной реализации компаратора:

```cs
list.Sort((x, y) => y.age.CompareTo(x.age));
```

Comment: у автора задача отсортировать по убыванию, а не по возрастанию

Comment: Это элементарно исправляется заменой знаков "больше" на "меньше". Спасибо за замечание! Исправил ответ.

Comment: я тоже думал, что ответ такой, но у автора что-то по-сложнее. студия запускается...

Comment: Исправил ответ, теперь сортировка по убыванию)

Comment: знаете, я думал, что всё сложнее, но оказалось, что нужно возвразать не `0`, а `-1` ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. мда-а. я о такой механике даже и не знал :)

Comment: у вас ещё 1 ошибка :) 1 нужно возвращать, когда `x.age <= y.age`: у вас `<` вместо `<=`

Comment: `list.Sort((x, y) => x.age > y.age ? -1 : 1)` — так наиболее правильно и коротко

Comment: Не совсем. У вас не учитывается ситуация, когда age равны. В целом, ничего фатального, сортировка всё равно будет работать правильно. Но в случае, если они равны, то будет осуществляться одна лишняя итерация, что может быть критично на больших объёмах данных. Я написал классический компаратор, где -1 возвращается, когда значение меньше (или, в случае по убыванию, больше), 0, когда значения равны и перестановка не требуется, и 1, когда значение больше (в случае по убыванию меньше).

Comment: так дело в том, что автор хотел именно этой лишней итерации, т.к. поля (кроме `age`) не будут меняться местами. это нужно уточнить у автора либо явно указать в ответе (по крайней мере, я бы так сделал). и да, я пишу именно такие методы сравнения, как у вас, т.е. в любом случае на в конце `return 0;`

Comment: `(x, y) => x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age)`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov лучший вариант, спасибо! :) только нужно обернуть это всё в знак минуса, для убывающей сортировки, или поменять x и y местами)

Comment: `y.age - x.age` не зайдёт?

Comment: @vp_arth - это может дать неверный результат, когда значения на грани `int.MinValue`, `int.MaxValue`. Вряд-ли кто-то будет такого возраста, но в общем случае...